# Parsing Data using Regex. Split it into columns via groups

Tags: python, regex, parsing, alteryx

I want to use REGEX to parse my data into 3 columns

Film data:
Marvel Comics Presents (1988) #125
Spider-Man Legends Vol. II: Todd Mcfarlane Book I (Trade Paperback)
Spider-Man Legends Vol. II: Todd Mcfarlane Book I
Spider-Man Legends Vol. II: Todd Mcfarlane Book I (1998)
Marvel Comics Presents #125

Expected output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6FGm.png)

I can see how to group it, but can't seem to REGEX it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKtge.png)

I built this expression: `(.*)\((\d{4})\)(.*)`

I want to essentially use the `?` quantifier to say the following:
`(.*)\((\d{4})\)**?**(.*)`
sort of like saying this group may or may not be there?

Nevertheless, it's not working.

Comment: How your data is presented? list? entire multiline string?, Series?

Comment: Series. Each of the five films has a seperate cell. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 2 capture groups, where the last 2 are optional:

```
^(.*?)(?:\((\d{4})\))?\s*(#\d+)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 1**
- `(?:\((\d{4})\))?` Optional non capture group capturing 4 digits in **group 2**
- `\s*` match optional whitespace chars
- `(#\d+)?` Optional **group 3**, match `#` and 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/WXDg5u/1).

Comment: Amazing! I haven't started working with optional capture groups yet. Thanks for this

Comment: I just tried the following: ^(.+?)(\(\d+\))?\s*(#.*)?$ and still found success. So the 'non capture group' isn't essential? We can just make a regular group optional? https://regex101.com/r/BS5fnN/1

Comment: @BenjaminStringer That also works, but in  that case you also capture the parenthesis.

Comment: ah! Great point. Thanks for your help. I've got a similar problem like this what I'm currently trying to solve. I have the feeling I need to use the optional non capture groups on this one? If you've got 5 minutes can you take a peek: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190041/regex-getting-the-follow-data-into-groups

Comment: @BenjaminStringer You can use a single pattern with an alternation, and then check if the values of the capture group exist, as now you have 5 groups `^(.*?)(?:(\(\d{4}\))?\s*(#\d+)?|(#\d+)?\s*(\(\d{4}\))?)$` See https://regex101.com/r/o3SUJX/1

Comment: that's really smart using the pipe operator like that and then matching the groups from the right hand side with the $. Thanks for that insight!