# Regex: getting the follow data into groups

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I've got the following 2 records:

| Input |
| --- |
| Marvel Comics Presents12 (1982) #125 |
| Marvel Comics Presents #1427 (1988) |

I want to parse it into the following format using RegEx:

| Title | Year | Serial Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marvel Comics Presents12 | (1982) | #125 |
| Marvel Comics Presents | (1988) | #1427 |

I do know basic RegEx but feel like I'm a little lackluster here. Is there a specific topic within RegEx that helps with this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating match groups for what's inside the parentheses and the number after the `#`, then use the same RegEx again to replace that text with nothing. Like this:

```
import re


def extract(el):
    year = int(re.search(r'\((.*)\)', el).group(1))
    el = re.sub(r'\(.*\)', '', el)
    serial = int(re.search(r'#(\d*)', el).group(1))
    el = re.sub(r'#\d*', '', el)
    return {'year': year, 'serial': serial, 'title': el.strip()}


data = ['Marvel Comics Presents12 (1982) #125', 'Marvel Comics Presents #1427 (1988)']
data = [extract(el) for el in data]
print(data)  # => [{'year': 1982, 'serial': 125, 'title': 'Marvel Comics Presents12'}, {'year': 1988, 'serial': 1427, 'title': 'Marvel Comics Presents'}]
```

The RegExs here are:

1. `\((.*)\)` to match what is inside the parentheses
2. `#(\d*)` to match the number after the `#` symbol.

I removed the match groups from the RegExs that replace text because they are not needed and might speed up the code a bit.

Comment: I like this approach! Another is using the pipe operator here thinking about it. Using the following RegEx: (.*)\s+\((\d*)\)\s+(#\d+)|(.*)\s+(#\d+)\s+\((\d+)\) .. just need to merge the null columns relative to position. 

Thanks for your approach

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to have the voting privilege. I do now! haha. Thanks.